# syntax for nested ifelse and if statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying to nest if and/or ifelse statements together in R and I can't quite get the syntax correct. I would like to perform some basic arithmetic: Referencing a similar dataset below, if the date is the same and if the location code is the same, I would like to subtract the pH values of codes A and B from the corresponding pH value for code F and enter the result into pHDelta. Or written out, A - F for a given date and location.

Thank you!

I am not certain the daset that I created below will appear correctly, please pardon me if it does not.

My dataset is similar to the following:

| Date | Location | Code | pH | pHDelta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22/07/01 | AA | A | 7.1 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AA | B | 6.8 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AA | F | 8.2 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AB | A | 7. 2 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AB | B | 7.8 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AB | F | 8.4 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AC | A | 7.5 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AC | B | 6.2 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AC | F | 8.3 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AD | A | 7.1 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AD | B | 6.8 |  |
| 22/07/01 | AD | F | 8.2 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AA | A | 7.1 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AA | B | 6.8 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AA | F | 8.2 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AB | A | 7.2 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AB | B | 7.8 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AB | F | 8.4 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AC | A | 7.5 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AC | B | 6.2 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AC | F | 8.3 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AD | A | 7.1 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AD | B | 6.8 |  |
| 22/07/02 | AD | F | 8.2 |  |

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use a group by approach - grouped by 'Date', 'Location', subset the 'pH' where 'Code' value is "F" (assuming only a single "F" per Location) and then subtract from the 'pH' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
     group_by(Date, Location) %>%
     mutate(phDelta = pH - pH[Code == "F"][1]) %>%
     ungroup
```

Comment: Woah. So I don't even need if statements. R is crazy.

There is only one "F" location per location, per date. It repeats per date. Let's see if I can get this to work.

Comment: @PaulWild the reason I specified one 'F' is that with a single element, it gets recycled.  whereas with multiple elements, there will be a length problem (as it is done in elementwise)

Comment: @PaulWild if more than one Date is present for Location, add the Date also in group by i.e. `group_by(Date, Location)` as in TarJae's solution

Comment: Even when adding Date in the group_by, I am still getting an error:

'Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `PhDelta = pH - pH[Chamber ==
  "FL"]`.
x `PhDelta` must be size 1, not 0.
i The error occurred in group 132: DATE = NA, LOC = "".'

Comment: @PaulWild that is a case when you have no `"FL"` values present.. You could do `pH[Chamber == 'FL'][1]` to force to NA.  With your example.  If i change the last element to `C` or so, it would still work

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I feel like I know just enough about R to get myself into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach: Because of the repetitive calculations we could also do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Date, Location) %>% 
  arrange(Code, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(pHDelta = pH-last(pH)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
  Date     Location Code     pH pHDelta
   <chr>    <chr>    <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 22/07/01 AA       A       7.1  -1.1  
 2 22/07/01 AA       B       6.8  -1.4  
 3 22/07/01 AA       F       8.2   0    
 4 22/07/01 AB       A       7.2  -1.2  
 5 22/07/01 AB       B       7.8  -0.600
 6 22/07/01 AB       F       8.4   0    
 7 22/07/01 AC       A       7.5  -0.800
 8 22/07/01 AC       B       6.2  -2.1  
 9 22/07/01 AC       F       8.3   0    
10 22/07/01 AD       A       7.1  -1.1  
# ... with 14 more rows
```

data:

```
structure(list(Date = c("22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/01", 
"22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/01", 
"22/07/01", "22/07/01", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", 
"22/07/02", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", "22/07/02", 
"22/07/02", "22/07/02"), Location = c("AA", "AA", "AA", "AB", 
"AB", "AB", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AD", "AD", "AD", "AA", "AA", "AA", 
"AB", "AB", "AB", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AD", "AD", "AD"), Code = c("A", 
"B", "F", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", 
"F", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", "F", "A", "B", "F"), pH = c(7.1, 
6.8, 8.2, 7.2, 7.8, 8.4, 7.5, 6.2, 8.3, 7.1, 6.8, 8.2, 7.1, 6.8, 
8.2, 7.2, 7.8, 8.4, 7.5, 6.2, 8.3, 7.1, 6.8, 8.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

Comment: This one worked. Originally it spit out a table in the Console. I needed to assign it to the original table for the pHDelta values to update.

Thank you.

Just doublechecking that it didn't upset any other data.

Comment: assign to `df` again like this: `df <- df %>% ...`